# Yii2 activerecord not returning database trigger value

Tags: activerecord, yii2, database-trigger

i just learned about YII2 framework, I'm just create a activerecord model. lets say `Item` and on table `item` i've just add a trigger before insert to add value a field. Im trying to test like this:

```
$item = new Item();
$item->name = 'item 1';
$item->save();
die(var_dump('<pre>', $item->attributes));
```

And trigger code something like this:

```
BEGIN
SET new.mycolumn = store_procedured_function();
END
```

And the dump result is

```
Array(
  ['id']=>
  int(123)
  ['name']=>
  string(6) "item 1"
  ['mycolumn']=>
  NULL
);
```

but when i'm check to database `mycolumn` not null and `id` return value. why `mycolumn` not showing the value like `id`? And how to get `mycolumn` value after activerecord function save()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For performance reasons Yii 2 does not automatically fetch attributes from database after save - in most cases it would not change anything, just create additional useless query. If you're relying on some database triggers, you may need to call [`refresh()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-activerecord#refresh()-detail) after `save()`.

```
$item->save();
$item->refresh();
var_dump($item->attributes);
```